# How to make a iterator point to a pre-allocated memory in C++ STL?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Something like in the example bellow. The alines assiging value to it.

```
{
uint8_t buffer[16];

#ifdef _WIN32
  std::vector<uint8_t>::iterator it_begin;
  it_begin._Ptr = (uint8_t*)buffer;
#else
  std::vector<uint8_t>::iterator it_begin((uint8_t*)buffer);
#endif

std::vector<uint8_t>::iterator it_end = it_begin + 16;
}
```

Ok, let me try to be more specific. I would like to call 'parse'function from raw pointer.

```
funcA(uint8_t* in, int32_t len) {
  // I would like to do:
  parse(req_, in, in + len); 
}


template<typename InputIterator>
std::tuple<result_type, InputIterator> parse(request& req, InputIterator begin, InputIterator end) {
    while (begin != end) {
        result_type result = consume(req, *begin++);
        if (result == good || result == bad)
            return std::make_tuple(result, begin);
    }
    return std::make_tuple(indeterminate, begin);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Raw pointers *are* a type of iterator. Thus, anywhere an iterator is requested, you can always pass a pointer into a pre-allocated buffer.

```
uint8_t buffer[16];

uint8_t* begin = buffer;
uint8_t* end = buffer + 16;
```

Since you have an array type there, you can use `std::begin` and `std::end` to automate the process of finding the start and end; this will make things easier if you later need to change the array size.

```
uint8_t* begin = std::begin(buffer);
uint8_t* end = std::end(buffer);
```

Comment: Iterators are not pointers. They abstract data accesses which may or may not involve operations with pointers.

Comment: Iterators are not pointers, no. But pointers are iterators - they satisfy all the requirements of Random Access Iterators.

Comment: That's asymmetrical: if iterators are not pointers then pointers are not iterators. Indeed, iterators are a generic concept to allow data traversal without concerning internal details. Consider more elaborated data structures like lists and trees or languages that don't have pointer but do have iterators.

Comment: Uh. Why would it need to be symmetrical? Your point about lists or other languages is also irrelevant. An iterator is a generic class of things that can be used to access sequential data. A pointer is a specific thing that can be used to access sequential data. Thus, pointers are a type of iterator. (Mind you, not all pointers can be _safely_ used in that way, if they only point to a single object. But C++ won't stop you from doing it anyway.)

Comment: How do you access a linked list or a tree sequentially with pointers? Iterators let you abstract that as if it were sequential; pointers cannot.

Comment: You're looking at the whole thing backwards, as if I'd said "iterators are pointers". I'm saying nothing of the sort (they aren't). Of course you can't access a linked list or tree sequentially with pointers. However, you can access an array sequentially with pointers. Thus, pointers are a type of iterator. Different tasks require different types of iterators.

Comment: I do agree with that: pointers are a _type_ of iterators. But pointers are not iterators as that would imply that iterators are pointers, which is totally wrong.

Comment: So really, this comes down to a question of the English language. In my experience, the word "are" does not mean equality. It can sometimes mean equality, but usually it means a subset relationship - there's a reason the term "is a" is commonly used for such things, after all.

Comment: @black: pointers are iterators like cows are animals. The subset/superset relation is **not** symmetric. _Some_ animals are cows, and _some_ iterators are pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You should not try to force `std::vector::iterator`s to traverse your raw array. If you are stuck with a raw array, but want to use iterators, then use `std::begin` and `std::end` from `<iterator>`

```
std::uint8_t buffer[16];

auto it_begin = std::begin(buffer);
auto it_end = std::end(buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Ty every one, it just works.

```
uint8_t * buffer_begin = (uint8_t*)in;
uint8_t * buffer_end = ((uint8_t*)in) + len;

std::tie(result, std::ignore) = this_->request_parser_.parse(this_->request_, buffer_begin, buffer_end);
```